# How to remove link option from image files in infobox with galleries in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I tried to create a gallery in an infobox on my personal server. I had a lot of trouble removing the ability to click to the image file's description page.

My gallery (part of a tabbed gallery of images):

```
<gallery>
    File:Dog 1.jpg|link=| Boxer
    File:Dog 2.jpg|link=| Beagle
    File:Dog 3.jpg|link=| Golden Retriever
</gallery>
```

According to MW's documentation, you should be able to deactivate a link to the image itself. But with a gallery, there is no way. Or maybe I don't know...

Comment: Unfortunately this appears to be a bug that has gone unresolved for at least 10 years: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T49646